# How to set up img size in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, image-resizing

I have trouble resizing my image in specific 
I set up .img in my index.css like this

```css
.img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

my portfolio.jsx is

```
<div className="container portfolio_container">
        <article className='portfolio_item'>
          <div className="portfolio_item-image">
            <img src={IMG1} alt="Pair Up" />
          </div>
          <h3>Pair Up</h3>
          <a href='https://github.com/Adipure/pairUp' className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>
          <a href='https://me0wmerz.github.io/pairUp/' className='btn btn-primary' target='_blank'>Live View</a>
        </article>
        <article className='portfolio_item'>
          <div className="portfolio_item-image">
            <img src={IMG2} alt="4AnimeArchive" />
          </div>
          <h3>4AnimeArchive</h3>
          <a href='https://github.com/Adipure/anotherAnimeArchive' className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>
          <a href='#' className='btn btn-primary' target='_blank'>Live View</a>
        </article>
        <article className='portfolio_item'>
          <div className="portfolio_item-image">
            <img src={IMG3} alt="Console.log" />
          </div>
          <h3>Console.log</h3>
          <a href='https://github.com/Adipure/console.log' className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>
          <a href='#' className='btn btn-primary' target='_blank'>Live View</a>
        </article>
        <article className='portfolio_item'>
          <div className="portfolio_item-image">
            <img src={IMG5} alt="weather" />
          </div>
          <h3>Weather Forecast</h3>
          <a href='https://github.com/Adipure/WeatherHomwork' className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>
          <a href='https://adipure.github.io/WeatherHomwork/' className='btn btn-primary' target='_blank'>Live View</a>
        </article>
        <article className='portfolio_item'>
          <div className="portfolio_item-image">
            <img src={IMG6} alt="snakeGame" />
          </div>
          <h3>Snake Game</h3>
          <a href='https://github.com/Adipure/snakeGame' className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>
          <a href='#' className='btn btn-primary' target='_blank'>Live View</a>
        </article>
        <article className='portfolio_item'>
          <div className="portfolio_item-image">
            <img src="#" alt="tbh" />
          </div>
          <h3>TBH</h3>
          <a href='#' className='btn' target='_blank'>Github</a>
          <a href='#' className='btn btn-primary' target='_blank'>Live View</a>
        </article>
      </div>
```

and I also set up .portfolio_item-image in portfolio.css like this

```css
.portfolio_item-image {
 border-radius: 1.5rem;
 -webkit-border-radius: 1.5rem;
 -moz-border-radius: 1.5rem;
 -ms-border-radius: 1.5rem;
 -o-border-radius: 1.5rem;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the result is the following,

[image]

I don't know why my second and 3rd image sizes are different from the others.
please help. thank you

I tried all CSS properties to resize them, but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you include the JSX template too? Maybe there is no initial height? Then `height: 100%` wouldn't work.

Comment: i just updated my jsx template

Comment: I would suggest to give these things concrete dimensions. Or at least a concrete height. Like `img { height: 200px; }` instead of `100%`. I suspect right now it's probably deriving the dimensions from the aspect ratio of the underlying image, and all the images probably aren't uniform.

Comment: @noodlejs 
when i give height:200px; property it changes all the picture sizes include my own img and other large pics.

Comment: Yeah but they should be consistent now. If you coupled a static height with `object-fit: cover;` they should be uniform size. From there, you can tweak the height as-needed to make it look good.

Comment: @noodlejs even though i change the heights, the smaller imgs are still same but i resized other imgs. Its 2nd and 3rd imgs that having a problem.